# how to implement "show recents" item on OS 10.9 and later

Tags: macos

I notice on Mac, every app on docker, when it's not opened and ctrl click it, there will be a pop-up menu, inside has a menu item called "show recents", when open the app this item will become "show all windows". I want to know how to make it work cuz right now, when I click it on my own app, it has nothing to show.

I have tested using doc controller and use noteNewRecentDocumentURL: method, but still, both "open recent" item in "file" and "show recents" in docker, it doesn't show my url I just added.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know, where you click on the app to show the menu. The recent documents list is shown

- in the app's *File* menu in the submenu *Open Recent*
- in the dock menu for the app as a list with one item per document
- likely at some other places related to the app

However where it is shown, the list is automatically managed by `[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]`, which is added to the project template for document-based applications. If you do not have a document-based application you should re-check, whether this would be the better choice. But you can use `[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]` in a non-document-based application as well:

> In some situations, it is worthwhile to subclass NSDocumentController in non-NSDocument-based applications to get some of its features. For example, the NSDocumentController management of the Open Recent menu is useful in applications that don’t use subclasses of NSDocument.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocumentController_Class/)

There is a section *Managing the Open Recent Menu* containing the description of the method [`-noteNewRecentDocumentURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocumentController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocumentController/noteNewRecentDocumentURL:) in the documentation of `NSDocumentController`. You have to send this message to the shared instance, 
whenever you want to add an item to the recent docs list:

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] noteNewRecentDocumentURL:theURLOfTheDocYourAppOpens];
```

Please note:

> Applications not based on NSDocument must also implement the application:openFile: method in the application delegate to handle requests from the Open Recent menu command.

If you do not want to use the document controller, you have to maintain the list yourself and add it to the different locations manually. You can start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/intro/dockintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986). I do not recommend that.

Comment: you can refer to that link, that's what I mean, and that's what I want to make it work on my app

Comment: Well, on my Mac (OS X 10.11.5) it is not shown in a submenu *recent items*, but directly in the dock menu. (Your link refers to posts from 2011!) However, this is, why you should use the document controller for that: If the location or the way it is displayed changes you do not have to take care about it. Simply use it as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that change. I just want to say, where is the right place to implement "show recents", I know I should consider to use document controller, but which is the right place? I mean, when I click the system menu item"show recents", what method will it fall through? Then in that method, I can use doc.

Comment: 1. Please change your Q. Most users will have 11.5 installed. 2. I edited my answer.

Comment: I used this doc tech, with noteNewRecentDocumentURL method called in applicationDidFinishLaunching:, but when I check the menu, there is no new recent item shows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code for use with Xamarin.Mac.

```cs
// Add the file to the menu. Note creation of file url.
void AddFileToOpenRecentMenu(string filePath)
{
    var fileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath);
    NSDocumentController.SharedDocumentController.NoteNewRecentDocumentURL(fileUrl);
}

// Open the file selected from the menu (in AppDelegate.cs)
[Export("application:openFile:")]
public override bool OpenFile(NSApplication sender, string filename)
{
    var keepFileInMenu = ProcessFile(filename);
    return keepFileInMenu;
}
```